# Paypal Payment Standard via Paypal Rest API

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am looking into implementing `Paypal Standard Payment` product. The basic reason being "**offsite payment**" (i.e. we dont want payments being captured at our own site, but on paypal's own payment page via redirection).

However, previously I used to get it done via (now called) `Classic API`.. I wounder if the new `REST API` supports this offsite / paypal redirect standard payment method? This is because there is no mention of these classic products names on the REST documents (instead, they are listed in Classic API section only)

Secondly, does Paypal Standard (even via REST) support Direct Card payments? or only Paypal Account payment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

REST does not encompass all Classic API features. It's mainly for mobile development (although not exclusive to that), using OAuth, which is more familiar to mobile developers. Payments Standard is not an API product at all but it can be used in conjunction with API calls to a limited extent. Classic API has the [Button Manager](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/button-manager/integration-guide/NVP/ButtonMgrOverview/) that lets you set up custom encrypted buttons that can start a Payments Standard payment.

REST does support [direct payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/) and supports almost everything Classic does in that regard.